# Java update JTable

Tags: java, swing, vector, jtable

my table should be editable so i implemented setValueAt(), but i dont't know how to set the value.I used Vector to store rows because i want to add new rows to my table..

```
  class TabelModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private String[] columnNames = { "Name", "Age" }; // 2 Spalten
    private Vector<Object[]> rows = new Vector<Object[]>();     

    public void addRowToEnd(String column1, String column2) {
        int rowCount = getRowCount();
        rows.add(new String[] { column1, column2 }); // Daten hinzufügen
        fireTableRowsInserted(rowCount, rowCount); // Tabelle updaten
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    // How can i set here the value?
        fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
    }
}
```

Best Regards

Comment: Well, since you have the row and column index and the value, presumably you'd just need to do `rows.get(rowIndex)[columnIndex] = aValue;` and then trigger a cell updated event

Comment: thanks, it works but i don't really understand it. Can you explain it a bit more?

Comment: [How to use tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) - The `TableModel` is just a communalised interface which allows the `JTable` to display what ever data you have - it doesn't care about "how" you structure your data, only that the `TableModel` provides a means to access it. When you call `setValue`, you simply need to convert the supplied information into a means by which you can access your underlying data structure and set the new value

Comment: yes i  have already read this , but i mean this: rows.get(rowIndex)[columnIndex] = aValue; i have never seen this before

Comment: `rows` is `Vector` of `Object[]`, so `rows.get(rowIndex)` returns a `Object[]`, so `rows.get(rowIndex)[columnIndex]` is just shorthand for getting the row from the `Vector` and the element of the array

Comment: Why don't you just use the `DefaultTableModel`? It is editable and allows you to dynamically add rows to the model. No need for any custom code. If you are going to create a custom model, then use an ArrayList to hold the data, not a Vector.